# Alternativa a regex101 que acepte modo unicode

Tags: javascript, regex

Recuentemente me platicaron acerca del modo unicode en JavaScript así que busqué algún artículo dispuesto a probarlo en el sitio [regex101](https://regex101.com/) pero al probar uno de los casos simples basado en [este sitio](https://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) me encuentro que no reconoce `\p{Alphabetic}` y me sale el error.

a los bloques \p{algo} se les conoce como "[Unicode property escapes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes)" (no sé como se les diga en castellano), pero parece que regex101 no los soporta.

> `\p` This token has no special meaning and has thus been rendered erroneous

[image: error en regex101.com]

De momento intenté probar mi expresón regular en la consola del navegador y allí funciona muy bien

```
console.log(/^x\p{Alphabetic}{2}$/u.test("x!!"))
console.log(/^x\p{Alphabetic}{2}$/u.test("xas"))
```

¿Existe alguna alternativa a regex101 que me permita probar expresiones regulares con símbolos bloques unicode?.

Comment: En el sitio regex101 puedes usar algunos bloques `\p{}` si marcas `golang` como lenguaje en vez de javascript. No obstante `\p{Alphabet}` sigue sin admitirlo, aunque sí admite `\p{Greek}` o `\p{Latin}`, por ejemplo. Parece que puedes seleccionar alfabetos, aunque no categorías.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunas opciones, pero antes quiero hacer un inciso importante.

Lo que intentas utilizar son 'RegExp Unicode Property Escapes', que forman parte del estándard ECMAScript 2018.

Actualmente, únicamente Chrome/Chromium soporta ECMAScript 2018 en su totalidad.

Aquí puedes ver una tabla comparativa

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Así pues, no se trata solo de buscar una utilidad que permita los Unicode Property Scapes, si no que además el navegador donde estés ejecutando la página también tiene que soportarlos.

Bajo estas dos condiciones he encontrado: http://scriptular.com/ (te funcionará en Chrome, pero no así en firefox, IE, Edge,... por lo comentado anteriormente)

Ten en cuenta que el standard ECMAScript 2018 es relativamente reciente y puede pasar algún tiempo hasta que sea soportado completamente por la gran mayoría de navegadores. Así que puede ser buena idea no utilizar esas funcionalidades hasta que estén bien soportadas por la gran mayoría de navegadores.

Pese a todo, también hay 'workarounds'. Existe la librería javascript "[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)", que extiende el soporte de las expresiones regulares.

Y también la siguiente página https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html que te permitirá probar expresiones regulares "XRegExp" (si pruebas en esta última página, ten en cuenta que las expresiones regulares probadas podrían no funcionar en tus desarrollos a menos que uses XregExp en ellos)

Comment: Scriptular me funciona al 100, freeformatter no, a pesar de la librería :/